# Binary File reading into dynamic array as garbage values

Tags: c++, structure, binaryfiles, dynamic-arrays

Hi trying to finish up some code and ran into an issue. My program is trying to write records to a binary file and then read them back when the appropriate functions are called. Whenever I try and read the file into the dynamic array so that I can format the output, only garbage values (I think the addresses?) are printed past some first text.

Here's the code I'm working with now,

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Inventory
{
 char desc[30];
 int qty;
 double wholeSaleCost;
};

// Function prototypes
void addRecord(fstream &);
void viewRecord(fstream &);
void changeRecord(fstream &);
bool validInput(char userInput);
// This function will add a record to the file
void addRecord(fstream &inventoryFile)
{
    Inventory recordUserInput;
    cin.ignore();
    char *tempWholeSale;
    char *tempQuantity;
    tempWholeSale = new char[sizeof(Inventory().wholeSaleCost)];
    tempQuantity = new char[sizeof(Inventory().qty)];



    cout << "Enter the following inventory data:" << endl;

    cout << "Description: ";
    cin.getline(recordUserInput.desc, sizeof(Inventory().desc));
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Quantity: ";
    cin.getline(tempQuantity, sizeof(Inventory().qty));
    while (!validInput(*tempQuantity))
    {
        cout << "That is not a valid input, please enter a number greater than 0." << endl;
        cout << "Quantity: ";
        cin.getline(tempQuantity, sizeof(Inventory().qty));
    }

    recordUserInput.qty = atoi(tempQuantity);
    cout << endl;


    cout << "Retail Price: ";
    cin.getline(tempWholeSale, sizeof(Inventory().wholeSaleCost));
    while (!validInput(*tempWholeSale))
    {
        cout << "That is not a valid input, please enter a number greater than 0." << endl;
        cout << "Retail Price: ";
        cin.getline(tempWholeSale, sizeof(Inventory().wholeSaleCost));
    }
    recordUserInput.wholeSaleCost = atof(tempWholeSale);
    cout << endl;



    // Adding record to the end of a binary file
    inventoryFile.open("C:/temp/inventory.dat", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);

    if (inventoryFile)
    {
        inventoryFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&recordUserInput.desc), sizeof(Inventory().desc));
        inventoryFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&recordUserInput.qty), sizeof(Inventory().qty));
        inventoryFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&recordUserInput.wholeSaleCost), sizeof(Inventory().wholeSaleCost));
        inventoryFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File Failed to open." << endl;
    }

}

void viewRecord(fstream &inventoryFile)
{
    int recordNumber;
    char * recordReadFromFile;
    int recordIterator = 0;
    recordReadFromFile = new char[sizeof(Inventory)];


    cout << "Enter the record number of the item: ";
    cin >> recordNumber;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << endl;

    // Reading from file

    inventoryFile.open("C:/temp/inventory.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);



    if (inventoryFile)
    {
        inventoryFile.seekg((sizeof(Inventory)*recordNumber), ios::beg);
        inventoryFile.read(recordReadFromFile, sizeof(Inventory));
        inventoryFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File Failed to open." << endl;
    }


    //Record Display
    cout << "Description: ";
    for (recordIterator; recordIterator < 32; )
    {
        cout << recordReadFromFile[recordIterator];
        recordIterator++;
    }

    cout << endl << "Quantity: ";
    for (recordIterator; recordIterator < 38; )
    {
        cout << recordReadFromFile[recordIterator];
        recordIterator++;
    }

    cout << endl << "Retail Price: ";
    for (recordIterator; recordIterator < 48; )
    {
        cout << recordReadFromFile[recordIterator];
        recordIterator++;
    }
}
```

Main just has an if/else block to call the different functions. The fstream object I'm working with is 'fstream inventoryFile'

The numbers for the cout display came from using a sizeof(Inventory.desc) etc. and I found that inv.desc was 30 bytes, .qty was 4 bytes and .wholeSale was 8 bytes (expected) but I can't find a way around the buffer issue when writing each structure member individually. Really appreciate any help that can be offered, working through these 2 issues has brought me to a standstill.

Comment: I don't have time to go through your entire program. Maybe you should just write a very simple (10 line?) program to do the specific thing that is failing. Here is some advice to improve how the community responds to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The values you're using when trying to print out the data you've read are all wrong. You used `sizeof` before, so why not use it again? Why not read directly into the members of an instantiated object like you write them out? It's not surprising the data doesn't make any sense the way you're reading and trying to interpret it.

Comment: In `addRecord()`, `sizeof(qty)` is 4 bytes on many systems, so at most you could read 3 digits from `cin.getline()`.  Consider using `std::getline()` instead of `cin.getline()` to read lines as variable-length `std::string` values, and then use `std::stod()` or `std::istringstream::operator>>` to parse them.  And your `viewRecord()` is outputting individual bytes read from the file, not the parsed `Inventory` fields. This whole code could use an overhaul

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>

#pragma pack(push, 1) // or your compiler's equivilent...
struct Inventory
{
    char desc[30];
    int qty;
    double wholeSaleCost;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

// Function prototypes
void addRecord();
void viewRecord();
void changeRecord();

void resetInput()
{
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');            
    std::cin.clear();
}

template<typename T>
void promptforNumber(const char *prompt, T &value)
{
    do
    { 
        std::cout << prompt << ": ";
        if (std::cin >> value)
        {
            if (value >= T(0))
                break;

            std::cout << "Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            resetInput();
            std::cout << "That is not a valid number, please try again." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    while (true);
}

void promptforRecordData(Inventory &item)
{
    std::cout << "Enter the following inventory data:" << endl;    

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Description: ";
        if (std::cin.getline(item.desc, sizeof(item.desc)))
            break;

        resetInput();
        std::cout << "Please enter a string less than " << sizeof(item.desc) << " chars." << std::endl;
    }
    while (true);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    promptforNumber("Quantity", item.qty);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    promptforNumber("Retail Price", item.wholeSaleCost);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void displayRecord(const Inventory &item)
{
    std::cout << "Description: " << item.desc << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Quantity: " << item.qty << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Retail Price: " << item.wholeSaleCost << std::end;
}

bool readRecord(std::istream &in, Inventory &item)
{
    if (!in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item), sizeof(item)))
        std::cout << "Failed to read inventory item." << std::endl;
    return in.good();
}

bool writeRecord(std::ostream &out, const Inventory &item)
{
    if (!out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&item), sizeof(item)))
        std::cout << "Failed to write inventory item." << std::endl;
    return out.good();
}

bool seekInToRecord(std::istream &in, int recordNumber)
{
    if (!in.seekg(sizeof(Inventory) * recordNumber))
        std::cout << "Failed to seek file." << std::endl;
    return in.good();
}

bool seekOutToRecord(std::ostream &out, int recordNumber)
{
    if (!out.seekp(sizeof(Inventory) * recordNumber))
        std::cout << "File Failed to seek." << std::endl;
    return out.good();
}

// This function will add a record to the file
void addRecord()
{
    Inventory inventoryItem;    
    promptforRecordData(inventoryItem);

    // Adding record to the end of a binary file
    std::ofstream inventoryFile("C:/temp/inventory.dat", std::ios::app | ios::binary);    
    if (!inventoryFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    writeRecord(inventoryFile, inventoryItem);
}

// This function will display a record from the file
void viewRecord()
{
    int recordNumber;
    promptForNumber("Enter the record number of the item", recordNumber);
    std::cout << endl;

    // Reading from file    

    std::ifstream inventoryFile("C:/temp/inventory.dat", std::ios::binary);
    if (!inventoryFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (recordNumber > 0)
    {
        if (!seekInToRecord(inventoryFile, recordNumber))
            return;
    }

    Inventory inventoryItem;
    if (!readRecord(inventoryFile, inventoryItem))
        return;

    inventoryFile.close();

    //Record Display
    displayRecord(inventoryItem);
}

// This function will change a record in the file
void changeRecord()
{
    int recordNumber;    
    promptForNumber("Enter the record number of the item", recordNumber);
    std::cout << endl;

    // Reading from file

    std::fstream inventoryFile("C:/temp/inventory.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if (!inventoryFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File Failed to open." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (recordNumber > 0)
    {
        if (!seekInToRecord(inventoryFile, recordNumber))
            return;
    }

    Inventory inventoryItem;
    if (!readRecord(inventoryFile, inventoryItem))
        return;

    //Record Display
    displayRecord(inventoryItem);

    // Overwrite record in binary file
    promptForRecordData(inventoryItem);
    if (seekOutToRecord(inventoryFile, recordNumber))
        writeRecord(inventoryFile, inventoryItem);
}
```